# How can i display correctly time

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, momentjs

I am building a code ,in Visual studio code with discord.js library. I want from the bot, when a user sends a command, reply with current date and time .

The code i am using is :

```
const moment = require('moment');
module.exports = {
    name: 'onduty',
    description: 'This is an ONDUTY command!',
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        var d = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0c0c0c')
        .setDescription(`**Ο ${message.author} μπηκε on duty στις :**\n`
        + `**${d}**`)
        message.delete()
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
        
    },
};
```

When i execute the command it sends for example : February 21 2021 13:59 but my time is +2 hours(15:59)

Comment: not sure what you mean by `+2` hrs?

Comment: is your server running in a different timezone?

Comment: What i mean Mr Daniel is that my server and my current time are 2 hours ahead in timezone. That's why the GMT +02:00. I don't know if you understand now Mr Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With moment you can declare any tz(TimeZone) here you have a [list of them](https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a).

Based on moment [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) here is an example:

```js
moment.tz("2013-12-01", "America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2013-12-01T00:00:00-08:00
```

To answer your question I took `Europe/Bucharest` which is GMT +02:00

```
var d = moment().tz("Europe/Bucharest").format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there (currently) is no way to display dates/times to Discord users in their own timezone.  Hopefully Discord will implement a 'tag' or something similar that would allow bots to send messages with date/times that the Discord client could then translate into the user's own timezone (as they currently do with message timestamps/etc).

[see this thread for more info](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360050695212/comments/1500000434202)